# Json regular expressions

Tags: json, regex, validation, schema, dispose

i want to check exact validation as my json coming

we are working on json schema validation need to validate a string with particular pattern

```
{"depend":"AT8H"}
```

I want to validate the value of depend as it is , like I need to check the character `A` and `T` as uppercase as it is and than anydigit and than again any character..

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to specify string pattern. Regular expressions in JSON Schema are described here https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/regular_expressions.html

In your case it would be something like this:

```
{
   "type": "string",
   "pattern": "^AT[0-9].$"
}
```

Comment: hi karol its not matching that string upto integer it is ok after the integer its not matching any character

Comment: @biyyapu You probably want `^AT[0-9].$` instead

Comment: @biyyapu I've changed it. I think I misunderstood your requirements before.

Comment: @KarolSamborski  this works fine and I have another query on this if I want to allow only uppercase how should we write the pattern..please write for the same string which means including the last character in the string it is also should be uppsercase only

Comment: maybe something like this: `"^AT[0-9][^a-z]"` ?

Comment: [^a-z] is not working it is accepting all characters but I want to accept only capital characters

Comment: if you want only capital letters then you should use `[A-Z]` instead of `[^a-z]`